# ViewBag with SelectList doesn't show in DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this in controller for fill the `ViewBag`.
The `_context` is database context.

```cs
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var categories = _context.Categories.ToList();
    ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryId", "Name");
    
    return View(new Exercise());
}
```

The `categories` collection seems filled correctly.

```xml
<div class="form-group">
     <ejs-combobox id="categories" dataSource="@ViewBag.Categories" fields-text ="Name" fields-value="CategoryId" placeholder="Select Category" popupHeight="220px" style="color:#fff">
     </ejs-combobox>
     <span asp-validation-for="Category" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

But when I run the code and open `DropDownList` it is blank.

I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Whatever kind of 3rd-party component `ejs-combobox` is meant to be, it is probably related to this one.

Comment: The resulting select list has the properties `Text` and `Value` not `Name` and `CategoryId`,  try: `fields-text ="Text" fields-value="Value"`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this instead `ejs-combobox` use `select` tag and use `asp-items` taghelper like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Category"></label>
    <select asp-for="Category" id="categories" asp-items="@ViewBag.Categories">
        <option value="">Select item</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Category" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was missing `e-dropdownlist-fields value="CategoryId" text="Title"></e-dropdownlist-fields>`
This helps with blank datas.

The second mistake was i use `combobox` instead `dropdownlist`